# ViewModel prevent refetching of data

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, kotlin

My viewModel refetches my data causing my shimmer to keep executing each time I get to this fragment, and also the data is beign refetched which is making my bill goes up on Firebase

How can I prevent to refetch again the data each time my fragment pops up ?

### From my view

```
 viewModel.fetchShops(location).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when(it){
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    shimmer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    shimmer.startShimmer()}
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    shimmer.visibility = View.GONE
                    shimmer.stopShimmer()
                    adapter.setItems(it.data)
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Error fetching data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

I call this in my `onViewCreated()` so each time this fragment recreates my `Resource.Loading` fires as well as the `fetchShops(location)` and this fetches again to my database, I want it to fetch just once each time I come back to this fragment, any idea?

### ViewModel

```
   fun fetchShops(location:String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try{
                emit(repo.fetchShops(location))
            }catch (e:Exception){
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Comment: What does `fetchShops(location)` do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `LiveData` instance every time `fetchShops()` is called. This means that any previously created `LiveData` (and the previous value it stores) is lost.

Instead, you should [Tranform your LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) by using your `location` as the input into creating your `liveData { }` block as per the [`liveData` with `Transformations`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) .

```
private val locationQuery = MutableLiveData<String>

// Use distinctUntilChanged() to only requery when the location changes
val shops = locationQuery.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { location ->
    // Note we use viewModelScope.coroutineContext to properly support cancellation
    liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try{
            emit(repo.fetchShops(location))
        }catch (e:Exception){
            emit(Resource.Failure(e))
        }
    }
}

fun setLocation(location: String) {
    locationQuery.value = location
}
```

You can then use this by updating your Fragment:

```
// Set the current location
viewModel.setLocation(location)

// Observe the shops
viewModel.shops.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        when(it){
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                shimmer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                shimmer.startShimmer()}
            is Resource.Success -> {
                shimmer.visibility = View.GONE
                shimmer.stopShimmer()
                adapter.setItems(it.data)
            }
            is Resource.Failure -> {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Error fetching data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: So so clean, thanks a lot @ianhanniballake , last question, does we always need to use distinctUntilChanged() for one shot operations also with switchmap ? thanks

Comment: @CoffeeBreak - well, generally you'd only call `setLocation` when the location actually changes. `distinctUntilChanged()` just means you can set it to the same value again and again without reloading